# error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol (C++)

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Say I have this function called DoThis(const char *abc) in a file called one.cpp. So when I attempt to call this function from another function in a different source file (two.cpp), I get the error: error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol (C++), even though I used #include "one.h" What would I do to fix this?

Comment: Is it also defined in one.h

Comment: The function DoThis is defined in the header.

Comment: are both files linked to the project?

Comment: Yes they are linked together.

Comment: How do you compile the programs?

Comment: Are you sure that the signature is exactly the same? Not typos in the name?

Comment: Don't worry, I solved it. Just add cdecl to the function ref in the header

Comment: @user2549990: You first stated that the function is defined in a `.cpp` file. Now you are saying that it is defined in the header (???). Do you actually understand what "defined" means? Function definition is the *function body*. Where does the function body for `DoThis` reside?

Comment: This is a linking related error having nothing to do with headers.

Comment: I had an error where my project was compiled as **x64** project. and I've used a **Library** that was compiled as **x86**.

I've recompiled the library as x64 and it solved it.

Answer (score 19):

That means that the definition of your function is not present in your program. You forgot to add that `one.cpp` to your program.

What "to add" means in this case depends on your build environment and its terminology. In MSVC (since you are apparently use MSVC) you'd have to add `one.cpp` to the project.

In more practical terms, applicable to all typical build methodologies, when you link you program, the object file created form `one.cpp` is missing.

Comment: But what if say my file is a header only file cause its an abstract class? Sorry to dig up old post :)

Comment: @Niklas Vest: If everything is there, in the header, then the compiler/linker should be able to find everything without any problems. I.e. LNK2001 simply will not occur. Placing inappropriate things into header files usually elevates risk of LNK2005, which is on the other end of the spectrum: too many definitions.

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like you are using Microsoft Visual C++.  If that is the case, then the most possibility is that you don't compile your two.cpp with one.cpp (one.cpp is the implementation  for one.h).

If you are from command line (cmd.exe), then try this first:
cl -o two.exe one.cpp two.cpp

If you are from IDE, right click on the project name from Solution Explore.  Then choose Add,
Existing Item.... Add one.cpp into your project.